# iPhone 6 Screenshot Size

Tags: ios, image, screenshot, resolution

I am using iTunes Connect to submit an iOS app and I wanted to get screenshots of the app on an iPhone 5 (4 inch screen) and an iPhone 6 (4.7 inch screen), both of which I own. Apple says the image sizes for the screenshots need to be 640x1136 and 750x1334 respectively

When I took a screenshot on the iPhone 6 of the app and sent it to myself through email, as the "actual size", the image was 640x1136, not 750x1334. Why is this?

In Xcode the iOS Simulator makes the app look much worse (lower quality imagery and glitching in some tables/images) so I don't want to take a screenshot from that. How should I go about getting a screenshot of the proper sizes?

Comment: It looks like your app is not optimised for iPhone 6. In that case you don't have to upload screenshots for 4.7" screen size to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Your iPhone 6 is in Zoom-Mode. You have to change it to normal mode. Go to Setting - Display & Brightness - View-zoom (translated from Germany).

The iOS Simulator brings full scale screenshots even if the simulator is scaled down due to your computers screen size.

**Edit:**
the iOS Simulator no longer brings full scale screenshots if scaled down, you have to scale to 100% to get the right dimensions on the simulator

Comment: Thanks bro, save my day.